# parallelize a for loop and populate multiple data structures

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, executorservice

I have a for loop that I want to parallelize. In my below code, I iterate my outermost for loop and put entries in various data structures and it works fine. And all those datastructures have a getter in the same class which I use later on to get all the details once everything is done in this for loop from some other class. I am populating `info`, `itemToNumberMapping`, `catToValueHolder`, `tasksByCategory`, `catHolder`, `itemIds` data structures and they also have getters as well.

```
  // want to parallelize this for loop
  for (Task task : tasks) {
    if (task.getCategories().isEmpty() || task.getEventList() == null
        || task.getMetaInfo() == null) {
      continue;
    }
    String itemId = task.getEventList().getId();
    String categoryId = task.getCategories().get(0).getId();
    Processor fp = new Processor(siteId, itemId, categoryId, poolType);
    Map<String, Integer> holder = fp.getDataHolder();
    if (!holder.isEmpty()) {
      for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : holder.entrySet()) {
        info.putIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
      }
      List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
      for (String key : holder.keySet()) {
        values.add(info.get(key));
      }
      itemToNumberMapping.put(itemId, StringUtils.join(values, ","));
      catToValueHolder.put(categoryId, StringUtils.join(values, ","));
    }
    Category cat = getCategory(task, holder.isEmpty());
    tasksByCategory.add(cat);
    LinkedList<String> ids = getCategoryIds(task);
    catHolder.put(categoryId, ids.getLast());
    itemIds.add(itemId);
  }
```

Now I know how to parallelize a for loop as in below example but confusion is - In my case, I don't have one object like `output` in below example. In my case, I have multiple data structures that I am populating by iterating for loop so I am confuse how can I parallelize my outermost for loop and still populate all those data structures?

```
private final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

List<Future<Output>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Output>>();
for (final Input input : inputs) {
  Callable<Output> callable = new Callable<Output>() {
    public Output call() throws Exception {
      Output output = new Output();
      // process your input here and compute the output
      return output;
    }
  };
  futures.add(service.submit(callable));
}

service.shutdown();

List<Output> outputs = new ArrayList<Output>();
for (Future<Output> future : futures) {
  outputs.add(future.get());
}
```

**Update:-**

I am parallelizing a for loop which is inside a do while loop and my do while loop runs until `number` is less than or equal to `pages`. So maybe I am not doing it correctly. Because my do while loop will run until all the pages are done and for each page, I have a for loop which I am trying to parallelize and the way I have set it up, it's giving `rejectedexecutionexception`.

```
  private void check() {
    String endpoint = "some_url";
    int number = 1;
    int pages = 0;
    do {
      ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
      for (int i = 1; i <= retryCount; i++) {
        try {
          HttpEntity<String> requestEntity =
              new HttpEntity<String>(getBody(number), getHeader());
          ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity =
              HttpClient.getInstance().getClient()
                  .exchange(URI.create(endpoint), HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
          String jsonInput = responseEntity.getBody();
          Process response = objectMapper.readValue(jsonInput, Process.class);
          pages = (int) response.getPaginationResponse().getTotalPages();
          List<Task> tasks = response.getTasks();
          if (pages <= 0 || tasks.isEmpty()) {
            continue;
          }
          // want to parallelize this for loop
          for (Task task : tasks) {
            Callable<Void> c = new Callable<>() {
              public void call() {
                if (!task.getCategories().isEmpty() && task.getEventList() != null
                    && task.getMetaInfo() != null) {
                    // my code here
                }
              }
            };
            executorService.submit(c);
          }
          // is this at right place? because I am getting rejectedexecutionexception
          executorService.shutdown();
          number++;
          break;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          // log exception
        }
      }
    } while (number <= pages);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to output something from your parallel code. You just take the body of the outer loop and create a task for each item, like this:

```
for (Task task : tasks) {
   Callable<Void> c = new Callable<>() {
      public void call() {
         if (task.getCategories().isEmpty() || task.getEventList() == null || task.getMetaInfo() == null) {
               // ... rest of code here
          }
       }
    };
    executorService.submit(c);
 }

// wait for executor service, check for exceptions or whatever else you want to do here
```

Comment: ok make sense.. Just to make sure the if check you have will be for `isNotEmpty` and `isNotNull` right? And inside that if check I can have everything in it? I have updated my question with the new code so can you let me know whether that looks right?

Comment: I am getting `RejectedExecutionException` exception while running the way you have suggested. I have updated my question again and provided some details on what I am doing. Can you take a look and let me know if there are any changes I need to do?

Comment: Is shutdown being called before you finish submitting all the tasks? If shutdown is mistakenly inside the for loop, that will happen.

Comment: I don't think so it is being called. I have updated the question with more details. Can you check whether I got that right or there is anything wrong?